# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted. I tried to find it but still can't find where i got out of bounds array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

what was i trying to do is a recursion of first 40 fibonacci numbers, when tried to launch a program, it's stopped at `return 0;`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 40
void sum(int arr[], int n1, int n2, int offset);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[SIZE] = { 0, 1 };

    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    printf("%d\n", arr[1]);
    sum(arr, 0, 1, 2);

    return 0;
}
void sum(int arr[], int n1, int n2, int offset)
{
    if (offset > SIZE)
        return;

    arr[offset] = arr[n1] + arr[n2];
    printf("%d\n", arr[offset]);
    sum(arr, n1 + 1, n2 + 1, offset + 1);
}
```

Comment: What if `offset == SIZE` in `sum`?

Comment: Why muck around with C-style arrays and preprocessor macros? Why not use `std::array` or `std::vector` that know their `.size()` and plain `const` or `constexpr` variables for constants?

Comment: Thank you for posting a good mcve, it was really easy to spot the error and help you :)

Comment: Since you are programming in C++, consider using `std::array<int, SIZE> arr;` and then `arr.at(offset) = ...`. You'd get an exception with something like `out_of_range: array::at: __n (which is 40) >= _Nm (which is 40)`.

Comment: `n1` and `n2` are both used as array index values too, but you don't check that they are in bounds.  Since you increment them with recursion, if they don't start out of bounds, they could eventually go out of bounds before `offset` stops your recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this check:

```
if (offset > SIZE)
    return;
```

That means if `offset` is equal to `SIZE`, it passes.

`arr[offset]` with `offset` being equal to `SIZE` refers to the 41 nth element.

This array only have `40` element, hence the corruption.

If you run your program in a debugger, it should stop at the crash and you would be able to look at the value of `offset` that caused the crash.

A solution for this would be to change the check to `if (offset >= SIZE)`.